# JSON stringify omits 'String'

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json object:

```
values: {
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String }
}
```

When running `JSON.stringify(values)` I get:

```
{"username":{"unique":true},"password":{}}
```

It omits `type: String`.

Any workarounds?

Comment: JSON.stringify skips all `Function` types when serializing, since they are not valid in JSON.

Comment: can i see a sample content of the values variable

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. What did you intend to use `String` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) omits values that are not valid JSON, including `undefined` and `Function`.

If you really *really* want to, you could use the `replacer` parameter (not sure how cross-browser this will be though) and work around this. This function will basically inspect to see if the value is a function, and it will return the function name. In your example, it will return `"String"`, since String is a global constructor function.

```
JSON.stringify(your_object, function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "function") {
        return value.name; // or value.toString() for the function body/declaration
    }

    return value;
});
```

Although, to be clear, you're better off using a string as your type, (`"String"` instead of `String`) no hoops to jump through then.

Answer (score 4):

try including the quotes:

```
values: {
  username: { type: "String", unique: true },
  password: { type: "String" }
}
```